# Google Map V3 Remove Markers before updating

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm asking you for help because i'm stuck on a problem for several hours and i don't find the end of this problem ...
Each time my markers list is updated when a visitor moves on the map, markers are added on top of those already added. I tried several ways to remove all the markers before updating but without success.

Here's my `initialize` function :

```
function initalize() {
    // Creating a new map
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("googlemap");
    mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        noClear : true
    });

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49, 2);

    // Add a control
    // Generate bunch markers
    var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.,-152.);
    var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(76,58 );
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    mapCanvas.setCenter(latlng);
    mapCanvas.setZoom(10);

    var lat, lng, category, json = [];
    var categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"];

    // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
    infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Marker Clusterer setup
    clusterer.cat1 = new MarkerClusterer(mapCanvas, [], mcOptions);
    clusterer.cat2 = new MarkerClusterer(mapCanvas, [], mcOptions);
    clusterer.cat3 = new MarkerClusterer(mapCanvas, [], mcOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, 'tilesloaded', function () {
        loadMapFromCurrentBounds(mapCanvas);
    }); 


    google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng, mapCanvas);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, 'click', function() {
        infoWnd.close();
    });
```

}

When the map is loadded loadMapFromCurrentBounds function is called :

```
function loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map) 
{

    // We first remove the markers before updating
    for(var i=0; i < markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = new Array();

    // First, determine the map bounds
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    // Then the points
    var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

    // Now, each individual coordinate
    var swLat = swPoint.lat();
    var swLng = swPoint.lng();
    var neLat = nePoint.lat();
    var neLng = nePoint.lng();

    var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(swPoint, nePoint);
    var center = map.getCenter();

    var searchUrl = 'searchdatabase.php5?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;

    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {

        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        var bounds1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) 
        {
            var categorie = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("categorie");
            var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
            //var icon = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("typeicon");
            var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng"))
            );

             if ( categorie in markers == false) {
                markers[categorie] = [];
              }

            var marker = createMarker({
                idvar : idvar,
                idtypelieu : TypeLieu[categorie],   
                position : latlng,
                title : name,
                // draggable: true,
                icon : categoryIcons[categorie],
                description : address,
                categorie : categorie,
            });
        }
    })
}
```

And here's the `createMarker` function:

```
function createMarker(options) 
{

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
      infoWnd.setContent(options.description);
      infoWnd.open(mapCanvas, marker);
    });

    if(mapCanvas.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()))
    {
        var lacategorie = options.categorie;

        $("#"+lacategorie).append("<span class=SubList><a href=Lieu-" +options.idvar+ "-"+options.idtypelieu+"-1.html>" + options.title + "</a></span>");

    }


    markers[options.categorie].push(marker);
    return marker;
}
```

And so my problem, each time `loadMapFromCurrentBounds` is called when the user is zooming in on or moving the map, markers are added but don't replace the previous one, so each cluster is incrementing at update, and markers are superimposed.

I have tried several ways to remove the markers but without success.

Can somebody help me find where is my error?

Comment: I see you are creating marker clusterers for each category, but I don't see you using them.  If you are using them you need to clear them out to remove the markers from the map. Where do you add markers to them?  Can you provide a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Where does your markers  array get created?  I don't see anywhere you doing `var markers;` If it's not a global variable it's likely to be local to your loadMapFromCurrentBounds function, so getting recreated each time you change the map bounds. So your attempt to delete markers is working on an empty (non-existent) array! Just stick `var markers;` at the top level of your JS to make it a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while (markers.length > 0) {
    markers.pop().setMap(null);
}
markers.length = 0;
```

Instead of setting markers to a new array, try setting the length to 0.  This is what I have in my code to clear the markers and it's working for me.

Instead of

```
markers[options.categorie].push(marker);
```

Make it

```
markers.push(marker);
```

Comment: I already tried replacing it by your code and tried again just now but still the same problem :(

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on.  The marker array is a 2-dimensional array. As far as I can tell, there is no reason to have the marker array act as a dictionary.  You should just be able to push the new markers directly to the array.  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

you can find how to remove the marker...

(or)

```
while (markers.length > 0) {
    markers.pop().setMap(null);
}
markers.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your markersArray is a global var then you can use the following function to clear it at any time.

```
function clearMarkers(markersArray) {
    if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```